# Why do I get an error trying to install my Python service in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, service

Ok, so I wrote a python service that simply writes to a file. I packaged it all up with cx_freeze, and installed it as a Service via the command prompt. It ran fine, but then I realized that the file it was to writing was in some weird directory, so I changed the service code to write the file to my documents. Here's the code for my Python Service:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event

class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "PySvc"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Python Test Service"
    _svc_description_ = "This is a service that simply writes to a file"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager
        f = open('C:/Users/Luke/Documents/test.dat', 'w+')
        rc = None

        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            f.write('TEST DATA\n')
            f.flush()
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)

        f.write('SHUTTING DOWN...\n')
        f.close()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

if __name__ == '__main':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```

This line:

```
f = open('C:/Users/Luke/Documents/test.dat', 'w+')
```

Used to look like this (when it worked):

```
f = open('test.dat', 'w+')
```

This was the only change that I made to the code.
This time when I attempted to install it in the cmd, it returned this frustrating error:

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\PySvc\PySvc.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..
```

What Happened? Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and realized how amateur I truly am. Somewhere along the way, I accidently deleted the last 2 '_'s in `if __name__ == '__main__':` as you can see in the code. Just goes to show you that you should check all your code before you ask a SO question! So I changed this:

```
if __name__ == '__main':
```

To this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```